# Angular JS SSL client-side authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssl, xmlhttprequest, ssl-certificate

Is it possible for angular js to forward self signed certificates for establishing `SSL/HTTPS` connection?

We're trying to insert a self signed certificate to establish https connection from a secured server through angularjs https service or `XMLHTTPREQUEST`, is it possible?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not talking about client certificates, but you're talking about giving your application a self-signed certificate to trust so that it can verify a 3rd party website?

Comment: Sorry, no. We would like our angularjs app to load a certificate and submit it to a 3rd party server for client authentication

Comment: Lester, in this case, it can't be a self signed certificate as a third party won't accept your signed certificate as a valid proof of identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular  JS can't use Client Side certificates. Here is why. Client side certificates are used to ensure that the client is one of those limited set of client that have access to the server, hence the access to the client side certificate is limited to certain clients only. Providing it the Angular JS script to any one requesting it defies the purpose.
If you use a self signed certificate (even though there is no mechanism in Angular JS to specify it), it won't help in using it for authentication as the server can't trust a self signed certificate.

I may be clear it up a bit more if you provide the purpose of the action you are trying to perform.